# How can I set data-sly-test case insensitive in sightly?

Tags: aem, case-insensitive, sightly, htl

I need to set the data-sly-test in order to achieve 'true' as test result comparing two strings in case insensitive way.

```
<div data-sly-test="${ properties.jcr:language == 'en'}">true</div>
```

where value of `properties.jcr:language` is 'EN'. data-sly-test in this case returns 'false' but I need that the result is 'true'.

Is it possible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It can actually be done in HTL/Sightly by forcing your variable to uppercase and then comparing:

```
<div data-sly-test="${ properties.jcr:language.toString.toUpperCase == 'EN' }">true</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [specification](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#12-available-expression-options) and my experience, you can't do this. Use [sling](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html) or [slice](https://cognifide.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SLICE) models or the plain [use api](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/sightly/use-api-in-java.html) for your logic.